# Convergence of $\sum_n e^{-a_nz}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Let $a_n > 1, n>0$ be an increasing unbounded sequence of real numbers. Is it true that $\sum_n e^{-a_nz}$ converges for all $z>0$? If not, then is it at least true that $\sum_n e^{-a_nz}(\log a_n)/a_n$ converges?

Standard tests (like the ratio test) do not help here, I think. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried $a_n=\log n$ or $a_n=\log\log(n+2)$?

Comment: Does increasing mean $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$? I think so, because you emphasize that the sequence is unbounded which would automatically be satisfied if  $a_{n+1} > a_n$.

Comment: @PaulFrost No, strictly increasing does not imply unboundedness. Take, for example, $a_n=1-1/n$.

Comment: @Botond Right, I erroneously assumed that the $a_n$ are integers.